# Is it possible to set default values if `Nothing` is encountered somewhere in a deep Lens lookup/assignment?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Is it possible to set default values if `Nothing` is encountered somewhere in a deep Lens lookup/assignment?

E.g. for lookup:

```
(Just (4, 3), 2) ^. _1 . (maybe (6, 5)) . _1 == 4
(Nothing,     2) ^. _1 . (maybe (6, 5)) . _1 == 6
```

Or perhaps more importantly, for assignment:

```
((Just (4, 3), 2) & _1 . (maybe (6, 5)) . _1 .~ 7) == (Just (7, 3), 2)
((Nothing,     2) & _1 . (maybe (6, 5)) . _1 .~ 7) == (Just (7, 5), 2)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `non :: Eq a => a -> Iso' (Maybe a) a` to create `Iso` between `Eq a => Maybe a` and `Eq => a` [(see also)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html#v:non).

```
(Nothing, 2) ^. _1 . non (6, 5) . _1 == 6
((Nothing, 2) & _1 . non (6, 5) . _1 .~ 7) == (Just (7, 5), 2)
```

Comment: A _caveat lector_ from the docs: "Keep in mind this is only a real isomorphism if you treat the domain as being `Maybe (a sans v)`."

Comment: Yes, it is mean that `((Nothing, 2) & _1 . non (6, 5) .~ (6, 5)) == (Nothing, 2)` or generally `(Nothing & non x .~ x) == Nothing`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems to be possible:

```
let
  df :: Functor f => a -> (a -> f b) -> Maybe a -> f (Maybe b)
  df d = lens (maybe d id) (const Just)

(Just (4, 3), 2) ^. _1 . df (6, 5) . _1 `shouldBe` 4
(Nothing,     2) ^. _1 . df (6, 5) . _1 `shouldBe` 6

((Nothing,     2) & _1 . df (6, 5) . _1 .~ 7) `shouldBe` (Just (7, 5), 2)
((Just (4, 3), 2) & _1 . df (6, 5) . _1 .~ 7) `shouldBe` (Just (7, 3), 2)
```

Note: I'm in the process of acquainting myself with Lenses, so if anyone knows of a better way of doing this please do tell — e.g. in case there is a built-in function equivalent to `df`.

Comment: [`non`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.1/docs/Control-Lens-Iso.html#v:non) (and in particular make sure to read the caveats there about lawfulness of this isomorphism)

Comment: Thanks @DanielWagner. That's a bit embarrassing. I actually did try using `non` before I wrote this question, but for some reason I tried to use it like so: `(Nothing,     2) ^. _1 . non (Just (6, 5)) . _1 == 6` which resulted in a type error.